# click on a link and go back to the link row without scroll back

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, hyperlink

I create a div box with css : overflow: scroll. Here is my code:

```
<div id="resultbox" style="overflow:auto">
    <div id="abc"><a id="p1" href="123.php" class="fac_result" >abc</a>
        <a id="p2" href="456.php" class="fac_result" >def</a>
        <a id="p3" href="789.php" class="fac_result" >ghi</a>
    </div>
    <div id="ccc">
        <a id="pt1" href="123.php" class="fac_result" >123</a>
        <a id="pt2" href="456.php" class="fac_result" >456</a>
        <a id="pt3" href="789.php" class="fac_result" >789</a>
    </div>
    <div id="kkk">
        <a id="s1" href="ddd.php" class="fac_result" >wer</a>
        <a id="s2" href="fff.php" class="fac_result" style="background-color:#C7C8CA">fff</a>
        <a id="s3" href="ggg.php" class="fac_result" >ggg</a>
    </div>
    <div id="opo">
        <a id="t1" href="qqq.php" class="fac_result" >rrr</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do so that after an user clicked a link after the page refreshed but it will still return user to the row that I just selected which is highlighted background with `background-color:#C7C8CA` but I don't wish to scroll down the page. I just want it bring me back the selected link within the div box only. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass id via hash eg `#id`. Let's assume you want to redirect user to this row scrolled:

```
<a id="s1" href="ddd.php" class="fac_result" >wer</a>
```

You would redirect using:

```
page.php#s1
```

`page.php` is supposed to be the same page where above link is defined.

---

Working example is right here, click on following link:

[My Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844837/click-on-a-link-and-go-back-to-the-link-row-without-scroll-back/7845469#7845469)

It would take you to my answer scrolled directly. The same technique is used here, here is the url:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844837/
click-on-a-link-and-go-back-to-the-link-row-without-scroll-back/7845469#7845469
```

As can be seen at the end, there is `#7845469` which is the id of row containing my answer.

Comment: No. That is not I want. I want after a page refresh scroll back to the inside div only.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing it cross pages?

You could use the scrollTo plugin, which can scroll inside a div.

http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Their examples are created that way: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

---

If you want it on pagereload, and are setting the background dynamic - then just do:

```
$('resultbox').scrollTo($('a[background-color=#C7C8CA]'));
```

Comment: This perhaps doesn't work to me. Because after a link is clicked whole page need to refresh.